# How to check if radiobutton in a row is unchecked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Private Sub Arr(ByVal arrRad() As RadioButton, ByVal arrLbl() As Label)
    Dim result As Integer = 0
    Dim temp As Integer = 0

    'arrRad is my control array Radiobutton, arrLbl is my control array Label
    'I have 15 Radiobutton and 3 Label
    For i As Integer = 0 To arrRad.Length - 1 Step 5
        If arrRad(i).Checked = True Then
            temp = arrRad(i).Text.Substring(0, 1)
        ElseIf arrRad(i + 1).Checked = True Then
            temp = arrRad(i + 1).Text.Substring(0, 1)
        ElseIf arrRad(i + 2).Checked = True Then
            temp = arrRad(i + 2).Text.Substring(0, 1)
        ElseIf arrRad(i + 3).Checked = True Then
            temp = arrRad(i + 3).Text.Substring(0, 1)
        ElseIf arrRad(i + 4).Checked = True Then
            temp = arrRad(i + 4).Text.Substring(0, 1)
        Else
            temp = 0
        End If
        result += temp
    Next
    txtKetQua.Text = result.ToString()
End Sub
```

I want to show `lblError` if that row radiobutton is unchecked, but I don't know how to show it

P/s: Sorry for my bad English

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a very shorter way using LInQ Extension `.Any()`:

```
lblError.Visible = Not arrRad.Any(Function(rb) rb.Ckecked)
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot <3

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my post as answer if you think it solved your problem ;-)